# ssh connectivity issue

Tags: ssh, redhat, centos5

I have a CentOS 5.5 server hosted in a remote data center.  I usually access this server from a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 server using the `ssh` command.  Now my organization has implemented a proxy server,  this is not allowing me to connect to the VPS server.

I see the following error using the command `root@<ip address>:-`:

```
ssh: connect to host <ip address> PORT 22: connection refused.
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: The only correct answer to your question is - Talk to your organisation and negotiate an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your organization has restricted outbound traffic.  SSH cannot be proxied over an HTTP proxy, so you will have to speak to your network administrators about allowing this access.

Comment: *Ahem* Corkscrew

Comment: Hadn't heard of that.  Website doesn't say how it works?  Anyway, I still think he should talk to his network administrators, as bypassing a proxy could be a violation of his security policy (it would be at my company, for example).

Comment: Indeed, he should go talk with the network admin. But, if you are wondering how it works, SSH client > Corkscrew > SSH Server.
Corkscrew will package ssh as HTTP. IF you have a blocked port, make SSH listen on port 443, should work ;-).

Comment: I understand packing the SSH data into an HTTP payload for transit through a proxy, I'm confused how the SSH server doesn't just throw it away as it contains HTTP headers, etc?

Comment: I've never examined a package but I guess SSH can work with HTTP-packages somehow.

Comment: Ok i will talk to my network administrator for this issue.